# Obtaining full chat transcripts

Tags: support, chat, chat-transcript

How do I download *all* chat messages or those from a particular room (over all time)?  A script may be able to do it, but is there a more convenient way?

Is there something at https://data.stackexchange.com/ all I see are the QA sites.

Answer (score 20):

In absence of any formal API, one can just obtain them by executing a `POST` request to `http://chat.stackexchange.com/chats/<room_id>/events` with form parameters:

- `mode`: `'Messages'` (there might be other modes, haven't checked.)
- `fkey`: A valid user's `fkey` is required.
- (optional) `msgCount`: integer, defaults to 100, capped to 500
- (optional) `before`: `message_id` to to get messages prior to. If missing, it gets the most recent `msgCount` messages

**[Example Jupyter Notebook.](https://gist.github.com/nicktimko/2b7e21c196d9e74c69fbd7f5b79014cb)**

The returned value is a mapping with the following keys:

- `ms`: Time it took for the query to run?
- `time`: Time since Aug 4, 2014 in seconds???
- `sync`: UNIX epoch time (mislabeled, or used to "sync" correct server-time to JS client?)
- `events`: a list of up to `msgCount` messages (may be fewer if there aren't that many.) Each is a mapping with the following keys:

  - `content`: HTML-formatted message; *may be missing if (removed).*; Begins with "" if there's more content which is not contained in the event record (i.e. it was a long message; the full content, if desired, has to be individually fetched).
  - `event_type`: `1`...only ever seen that. Other `event_type` values are used within the WebSocket based communication for an active chat page. They can be seen from a chat room's main page through [the use of `CHAT.addEventHandlerHook()`](https://stackapps.com/questions/8268/how-do-i-get-notified-of-events-in-se-chat).
  - `message_edits`: Integer, *may be missing if not edited.*
  - `message_id`: Integer; unique across all rooms on the chat server, but not between servers.
  - `message_owner_starred`: Boolean; If true, the message is pinned. *Normally not present if the message is not pinned.*
  - `message_owner_stars`: Count of pins. It's unclear if this can be anything other than 1 or not present. *Normally not present if the message is not pinned.*
  - `message_starred`: Boolean; If true, the message has been starred. *Normally not present if the message is not starred.*
  - `message_stars`: Count of stars for this message. *Normally not present if the message is not starred.*
  - `moved`: Boolean; If true, then this message has been moved from another room into its current room. *Usually missing if the message has not been moved*.
  - `parent_id`: Integer; Message ID to which this event is replying. May be an actual reply or just an `@`-ping. If it's the result of an `@`-ping, then this is the message ID of the most recent message by the pinged user. *Usually missing if the message is not a actual or `@`-ping reply.*
  - `room_id`: Integer
  - `room_name`: String; This is not present for events received via AJAX POST, but is present for events received by event listeners added via `CHAT.addEventHandlerHook()`.
  - `show_parent`: Boolean; If true, then this is an actual reply and the replied-to arrow is shown. *Usually missing if the message is not a direct reply.*
  - `time_stamp`: UNIX epoch, second-precision.
  - `user_id`: Integer, Chat.SE/Chat.MSE/Chat.SO user. Chat.SE ID is not related to a specific site or network ID; Chat.MSE and Chat.SO user IDs usually match the profile ID of the user on MSE and SO respectively, but that's not required. *May be missing if the user_id no longer exists.*
  - `user_name`: Name associated with `user_id` when the message was posted. If the user changes their username later, this does not update.

Comment: Tiny addendum: `user_id` ... *may be missing if user no longer exists* (At least that's my guess why, see eg message id 35969027, room 118)