# How can I download the chat history?

Tags: feature-request, support, chat

This question was asked in "[Obtaining full chat transcripts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129374/obtaining-full-chat-transcripts)", that has one complicated answer. In case of someones are not strong in programming (I am working in Philosophy, Health and etc communities) this answer is not usable.

Is there a feature which allows us to download the chat discussion history to save on a local computer and open it in a documentation program (for example Microsoft Word)?

For example in comparison of Wikipedia, I have this as a suggest for add a simple future to download `SE` contents (Q.A story or Chat one)

Comment: Copy and paste?

Comment: Better way! With more documentation futures. How you download a Wikipedia article as pdf? !

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such built-in feature.

You can visit the transcript of the chatroom of choice and then use the print or save as feature of your browser to get an off-line copy. Or use one of the tools/scripts you found yourself.

For Q/A pairs you can use more user friendly tools as explained in  [Printing out Stack Overflow/Exchange Q&As including comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22877/printing-out-stack-overflow-exchange-qas-including-comments) among others.

As I don't expect much need for such feature, not taking into account the complexities that comes with implementing this, the timeline for this feature to be added is many 6 to 8 years. That is also due to the fact that chat isn't high on the priority list as it isn't at the core Q/A.

Comment: Is it possible for us, suggestion SE to add this future for exporting our discussion or Q.A story?

Comment: Well, you just did with your feature request, right?

Comment: Almost SE is going to become a reference. There is a potential to produce an article with using some Q.A stories. Same as Wikipedia, producing this future, may useful for us.

Comment: On StackOverflow.com no-one needs that. If you can't explain how a feature will improve overall post quality or how it could make money within the goal and vision of Stack Overflow, Inc. no developer time will be dedicated to it. No one wants to spend money on a feature that encourages usercontent to be reproduced in off-line documents that hardly ever benefits anyone else.

Comment: Now, Stack Overflow is a branch in Stack Exchange and there is many communities that not all of users are member of that community. (Stack Overflow)

Comment: They are part of the same network, and they all run the same software. Although there are many communities size does matter. Even if you bring in all other communities I still doubt your feature would be useful for a large group of users. Maybe on the theoretical science sites, on Academia.se, maybe writers.se but that is about it.

Comment: Finally its mean SE not supported this future to download our content as said above?

Comment: Its not currently a feature. Chat's also kind of not something in active development. Never say never, but its not something we have right now, or soon.

Comment: I clicked "save as" in Google Chrome on Ubuntu, but when I opened the saved file, only the background showed up (none of the actual chat messages!)

Comment: Tried also in firefox now. Also tried opening the saved file in both Chrome and Firefox. The background is there but no chat messages, are you sure it works?

Comment: @user1271772 I tried [this transcript page](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/721/2018/11/10) from Chrome/Win10 and opened it in Edge and that works for me. Be sure to visit the full transcript, not the live chatroom as that "page" is build-up dynamically with JavaScript which is not run at the save as action.